# if statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript

'HTML'

```
<div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Current Price:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="current_price" name="current_price" placeholder="Enter Current Price" onkeyup="movement()" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 mt-2 row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Movement:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <select class="form-select" id="movement" name="movement" onchange="movement()" required>
                                <option value="">--Select Movement--</option>
                                <option value="Increase">Increase</option>
                                <option value="Rollback">Rollback</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Price Movement:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price_movement" name="price_movement" onkeyup="movement()" placeholder="Enter Price Movement" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-2 row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">New Price:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="font-weight: bold;" id="new_price" name="new_price" placeholder="New Price" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

'My java script code'

```
function movement(){
            var increase = document.getElementById('movement').value = "Increase";
            var rollback = document.getElementById('movement').value = "Rollback";

            var current_price = document.getElementById('current_price').value;
            var price_movement = document.getElementById('price_movement').value;

            if (increase = "Increase"){
                var total_increase = parseInt(current_price) + parseInt(price_movement);

                if (!isNaN(total_increase)) {
                document.getElementById('new_price').value = total_increase;
                }
            }

            if (rollback = "Rollback"){
                var total_rollback = parseInt(current_price) - parseInt(price_movement);

                if (!isNaN(total_rollback)) {
                document.getElementById('new_price').value = total_rollback;
                }
            }
        }
```

I try to make a Addition and Subtraction operation in my project when the user select an Increase in Select option tag and the javascript do the Addition Operation. and when the user select an Rollback in select option tag and the javascript do the Subtraction Operation.

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the value from the select input like this:

```js
function movement() {
  const value = document.getElementById('movement').value;
  var current_price = document.getElementById('current_price').value;
  var price_movement = document.getElementById('price_movement').value;

  if (value === "Increase") {
    var total_increase = parseInt(current_price) + parseInt(price_movement);

    if (!isNaN(total_increase)) {
      document.getElementById('new_price').value = total_increase;
    }
  }

  if (value === "Rollback") {
    var total_rollback = parseInt(current_price) - parseInt(price_movement);

    if (!isNaN(total_rollback)) {
      document.getElementById('new_price').value = total_rollback;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mb-3 row">
  <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Current Price:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="current_price" name="current_price" placeholder="Enter Current Price" onkeyup="movement()" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mb-3 mt-2 row">
  <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Movement:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <select class="form-select" id="movement" name="movement" onchange="movement()" required>
      <option value="">--Select Movement--</option>
      <option value="Increase">Increase</option>
      <option value="Rollback">Rollback</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mb-3 row">
  <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Price Movement:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price_movement" name="price_movement" onkeyup="movement()" placeholder="Enter Price Movement" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mb-2 row">
  <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">New Price:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="font-weight: bold;" id="new_price" name="new_price" placeholder="New Price" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro you get my point. :)

Comment: Bro, I have error. movement is not a function.